# Date Picker connecting with script

Tags: javascript, function, datepicker

Hi I have a datepicker:

```
  <input class="dmxCalendar2" name="dmxCalendar21" id="dmxCalendar21" />
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(
function()
 {
 jQuery("#dmxCalendar21").dmxCalendar2(
     {"altFormat": "yy-mm-dd", "condDates": [], "firstDay": 1, "showOn": "both",            
    "duration": "slow", "showOptions": {"direction": "up", "easing": "swing"},"yearRange": "c-  10:c+10", "onSelect": "MM_goToURL(\'parent\',\'allactstest.html\');"}
   );
  }
  );

 </script>
```

And also a script:

```
<script>
var chosenDate = '2012-08-14'; 
function checkDate(rgn, doIt) {
if (doIt('{dsDates::datebooked}') == chosenDate) {
    Spry.Utils.addClassName('id'+doIt('{dsArtists::@id}'),'hidden');
}
}
</script>
```

But I need it so the when the date is changed in the datepicker the 'var chosenDate part of the script is changed with it?